# Spring Cloud Version in a microservies system

Tags: java, spring-cloud

In a spring microservices, do i need to use spring cloud version be the same in all my project (Example version 2020.2 with 2020.3 or older hoxon) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a microservice is independend.

Microservices - also known as the microservice architecture - is an architectural style that structures an application as a collection of services that are

1. Highly maintainable and testable Loosely coupled
2. **Independently deployable**
3. Organized around business capabilities.
4. Owned by a small team

Comment: Thanks guys, I have tried a different in my system. It still works